# iOS 5 Storyboard Custom Cell Crash: UITableView dataSource must return a cell

Tags: iphone, ios5, cell, storyboard

This is either an XCode bug, or me missing a crucial rule here.

**Update:**
- What's the chance of this being a weird bug in XCode/Storyboard?

**Situation:**

- iOS 5, Storyboard
- This is the storyboard setup: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQBZk.png
- Another screenshot of the full setup: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDbuW.png
- TableViewController with Custom Cell, cell has reusable identifier "NewCell"
- in "cellForRowAtIndexPath" I basically have:

  `UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"NewCell"];
  return cell;`
- This throws an exception:

  `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'`

**Things I have already tried:**

- I setup a new project from scratch, TabBarController, with a TableViewController and a Custom Cell, all wired up in Storyboard, set a reusable cell identifier. Used the same code as above, **worked perfectly**. I don't know why it didn't work with the storyboard above...

I have a feeling it has something to do with the tree I built there, which is a TabBarController, loading a NavigationController, loading a TableViewController, providing a few items, one is clicked, which loads another TableViewController, which is unable to work with the custom cell, somehow.

**Important:**
  - The issue is that the Storyboard should make sure that:
    `UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"NewCell"];` will never return NIL (unlike without the Storyboard/iOS4). But, mine is nil. And I can't, for the hell of it, figure out what's happening.

Answer (score 2):

Heyo, I just had this problem today and figured out a few possible causes. To link a UITableView as a subview of a ViewController in Story board check that you have done these steps.

1. In your "ViewController.h", add `<UITableViewDataSource>` to your list
   of protocols

   @interface ViewController : UIViewController
   `<UITableViewDataSource>`

   you might want to add `<UITableViewDelegate>` as well but I didn't.
2. In your "ViewController.m" set up your Table view data source
   functions

   ```
   #pragma mark - Table view data source

   - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
   {
       // Return the number of sections.
       return 1;
   }

   - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
   {
       // Return the number of rows in the section.
       return [yourCells count];
   }

   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {

       NewCell *cell = (NewCell *)[tableView 
                                              dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"NewCell"];
       if (cell == nil) {
           NSLog(@"Cell is NIL");
           cell = [[CustomCell alloc] 
                   initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
       }

       return cell;


   }
   ```
3. In Storyboard, connect the UITableView's "Data Source" and
   "Delegate" references to the ViewController.
4. In Storyboard, give the Prototype Cell the Identifier "NewCell"

If these are done, I believe it should work.

Hope this helps =)

Answer (score 1):

I always use custom cells in the storyboard like this:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
return cell;
```

Make sure the number of rows/sections is at least one. And another thing to check is that you set the UITableViewController to your custom class name in the storyboard.

Comment: This isn't how you setup up a cell using Storyboard.

Comment: yeah, that's the great new thing about storyboards, see here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/Miscellaneous/RN-AdoptingStoryboards/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011297 - configuring table views: it will never return NIL again...

Answer (score 0):

- Did you double check the cell prototype identifier is "NewCell"?
- Your setup as Tabbar->navigationcontroller->tableview is perfectly fine. I
  am using this layout all the time.
- verify also there's no useless runtime attributes anywhere in this
  viewcontroller/tableview/cell.
- your prototype looks a bit weird there - you added a UIButton to the cell as subview? why?

Comment: a) checked b) it's actually tabbar->navcontroller->tableviewcontroller->tableviewcontroller->tabview->customcell  c) nope  d) added the button and random stuff just to see if anything shows... had just labels before that

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem add the following just above your dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier statement:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"NewCell";
```

making sure the identifier matches the prototype cell in Storyboard

Comment: I actually had tried that as well, without success. here's a screenshot of the full setup: http://i.imgur.com/1tVuz.png

Answer (score 0):

It maybe late to answer this but i bet [this](http://www.g8production.com/post/13498045139/uitableviewcell-in-storyboard-static-dynamic-custom) will fix all your problems