# Assertion failure in -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2935.137/UITableView.m:6509

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

**iOS 7:**

```
Exception Detail: *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2935.137/UITableView.m:6509
```

**Code:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 64, UISIZE.width, UISIZE.height -64) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
self.tableView.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeOnDrag;
self.tableView.delegate = self;
self.tableView.dataSource = self;

self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] init];
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;

[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:NSStringFromClass([GWVipRechargeCell class]) bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"GWVipRechargeCell"];
[self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
```

}

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
GWVipRechargeCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"GWVipRechargeCell"];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"GWVipRechargeCell"];
}
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
return cell;
```

}

I found Exception breakpoint jump at `self.tabelView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;`

some sets of tabelview :

```
self.tabelView.dataSource = self;
self.tabelView.delegate = self;
self.tabelView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] init];
self.tabelView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

I try all answers of [iOS 5 Storyboard Custom Cell Crash: UITableView dataSource must return a cell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8796669/6122246) ,but it still crash at `self.tabelView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;`

**Solution:**
 i move the settings order

```
self.tabelView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
self.tabelView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] init];
```

and it Run successed! i'm confused too!!!

if I set tableHeaderView also have this question

Comment: are you using .xib file for cell ?

Comment: your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is probably returning `nil` - have you checked that?

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya yeah

Comment: @Paulw11 already checked, the code is posted.

Comment: The posted code does not check for nil. Did you check with the debugger?

Comment: @BingChen check my answer and follow small instruction that i post in my answer your problem will be solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 [self.YOURTABLEVIEW registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"YOURCUSTOMCELL" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"YOURCUSTOMCELL_IDENTIFIER"];

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    YOURTABLEVIEWCELL_CLASS *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"YOURTABLEVIEWCELL_IDENTIFIER"];

    if (cell == nil) {

       NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"YOURTABLEVIEWCELL_IDENTIFIER" owner:self options:nil];
       cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    // here write your cell coding like give value to your lable, image , etc.
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: if in [self.YOURTABLEVIEW registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"YOURCUSTOMCELL" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"YOURCUSTOMCELL_IDENTIFIER"]; this line show error then use 

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 [super viewDidLoad];
 UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"YOURCUSTOMCELL" bundle:nil];
 [[self tableView] registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"YOURCUSTOMCELL_IDENTIFIER"];
}

Comment: @BingChen now what error you got and update your question with new code and put in UI of your storyboard that show .xib file and its custom class

Comment: if (cell == nil) {
        // Load the top-level objects from the custom cell XIB.
        YOURTABLEVIEWCELL_CLASS *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"YOURTABLEVIEWCELL_IDENTIFIER"];
    } 
//this will always return nil if cell == nil

Comment: @Dev_Tandel now its ok. check my answer .

Comment: @Himanshu ...it is working for Bing Chen is what required..thanx for helping

Comment: @Dev_Tandel ya now problem solve but you just give me down vote for the single line that i just forgot it so give me down vote but without it in my project its working fine.

Comment: Himashu.. it might be working  in your code because you might have never get cell == nil.

Down voted because it was simple logical issue. But as this is working down voted is removed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    GWVipRechargeCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"GWVipRechargeCell"];
    if (!cell) {
       // if cell is empty create the cell
        cell = [[GWVipRechargeCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"GWVipRechargeCell"];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: this is the correct one, cell will not return nil after this code

Answer (score 0):

set the tableView other properties before set tableHeaderView or tableFooterView like this:

```
// set tableView's other properties
tabelView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;

// set tableHeaderView or tableFooterView after set tableView's other properties
tabelView.tableHeaderView = headView;
tabelView.tableFooterView = footerView;
```